# Como expressar data e hora no formato "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", com zona UTC−03:00

Tags: php

Seguindo a documentação, estou tentando representar a data no seguinte formato:

> 2017-01-07T11:20:00-03:00

Código:

```
$dt = $_POST['data-emissao'];
$date = new DateTime($dt, new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
$data= $date->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP");
echo $data;
```

e estou obtendo:

> 2017-01-07T13:32:00-02:00

**Referência**: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, está correto o retorno, estamos no Horário de Verão. Você definiu o Time Zone "America/Sao_Paulo" que no momento é -02:00 ao invés de -03:00.

Se você deseja obter *sempre* -03:00 independente do Horário de Verão então o mais simples é usar uma string literal `-03:00`, já que não faz diferença o Horário de Verão.